# Ionic 4 and Angular 7 timeout and catchError cannot be found on a get request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I upgraded my project to ionic 4 and angular 7 and I fixed all the imports and errors in the code, to make it work according to Angular 7 changes.

The only think I am not able to solve it the following using `HttpClient`:

```
if (params.method == 'GET') {
  return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: request_params, withCredentials: true})
          .timeout(10000)
          .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler()));
}
```

I am getting 2 errors, the first is:

> Property 'timeout' does not exist on type
>   'Observable'.ts(2339)

And:

> Cannot find name 'catchError'. Did you mean 'RTCError'?ts(2552)

`this.errorHandler()` is to send an error if something went wrong.

Comment: Do you use `import { catchError, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';` to import `catchError` and `timeout` ?

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda still having error on `timeout` the other was imported and worked properly now.

Answer (score 2):

By using Angular 7, you are using RxJS 6+, you have done some of the migration but you forgot to put `timeout` in the `pipe`.
Also, if you want to pass a function to `catchError` just pass it without calling it (without parenthesis)

```
if (params.method == 'GET') {
  return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: request_params, withCredentials: true})
          .pipe(
              timeout(10000),
              catchError(this.errorHandler)
           );
}
```